# Eclipse Juno C++ build takes a long time

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, build, eclipse-juno

I want to start learning C++ but it becomes really irritating when you have to wait up to 3 minutes for a simple two line program to build and run. I've tried multiple things like completely disabling build logging, disabling generate scanner info command inside the discovery options and something else (sorry I cannot remember).

Another thing is that sometimes it's the build that takes a long time, and other times it's the actual opening of the [filename].exe It hits 70% on the progression bar then will just stop for a minute, sometimes I try pressing the run button again and it ends up executing the program twice.

It's not completely necessary that I get this fixed but it would be a big help. Please tell me anything I can do to fix this. No doubt most of you coding in C++ has encountered this at some point.

Comment: True, Eclipse is very slow, especially when you are starting it up. That is the way its been, slow at the start but will run fine as you continue coding. I suggest you try Codeblock IDE and see if that works better for you.

Comment: @Juniar I've tried codeblocks and I get the same problem

Comment: How big is your code? How many other programs & software do you have installed or running on your computer? I suggest you try running a simple code and Running your IDE in Windows Save Mode if you are using windows, you might have a lot of programs running at the same time. Also, I suggest using not very old PC or Laptop. Eclipse might be slow because it is written in Java. You can also try Emacs or Microsoft MSVC IDE. Microsoft MSVC runs greats on my 4.00 GB, 64-bit, AMD processor.

Comment: @Juniar I tried using MSVC and it works perfectly, obviously I need to get used to it since it's different to Codeblocks and Eclipse but other than that it's great. Thanks for the help Juniar